# Linux Windows на одной "машине"

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot

На одном компе установлено две ОС Linux и Windows , появилось необходимость поставить вместо Linux Debian , как переустановить что бы windows остался целым ? 
Раньше я просто удалял директорию linux и соответственно это приводило к разрушению обоих систем - как это реализовать без последствий ??

Comment: Диск для второй системы ? А вы Дебиан в магазинах видите ?

Comment: "Приобрести отдельный диск для второй системы " - это вы же написали !

Comment: Серёжка ты о HDD говоришь ??

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38436/discussion-between-lenovoid-and-sergey).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При установке выбираете ручную разметку диска, форматируете раздел, на котором была установлена старая система (linux), после форматирования устанавливаете этот раздел как корневой каталог для дебиана. Раздел, где установлен windows вы не затрагиваете.

Comment: ну в принципе да ! я отмечу Лучшим - но так делал - убил две системы сразу

Comment: Может быть, вы не "убили" обе системы, а просто потеряли загрузчик для windows? Вообще, при установке grub обновляется сам, но, при необходиости, можно указать ему раздел с загрузчиком windows.

Comment: я не знаю - как называется это  - но и винду и ubuntu - обе не доступны были , естественно я всё заново сделал но - обида осталась - столько полезного там было

Comment: @LenovoID зря все убили. Это и правда была проблема с загрузчиком. Уже неоднократно такое было и все решалось на несколько минут